# How to access GitLab instance container inside the GitLab Runner container to clone the repository on the same machine?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am fully aware that setting up GitLab and GitLab Runner on the same machine is a bad practice, but I have done it solely for testing purposes. I installed GitLab and GitLab Runner via docker on Ubuntu OS.

The pipeline gives the following error:

[image]

As you see, the runner can't clone from the repository. What I have done so far is:

This is the docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  gitlab:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    hostname: 'localhost:180'
    container_name: 'gitlab'
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - gitlab-network    
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://localhost:180'        
    ports:
      - '180:80'
      - '1443:443'
      - '122:22'
      - '1587:587'
    volumes:
      - 'gitlab_config:/etc/gitlab'
      - 'gitlab_logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - 'gitlab_data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    shm_size: '6gb'
  gitlab-runner:
    container_name: 'gitlab-runner'
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest'
    networks:
      - gitlab-network      
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./config:/etc/gitlab-runner
    restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  gitlab_config : {}
  gitlab_logs : {}
  gitlab_data: {}
networks:
  gitlab-network:
    driver: bridge
```

This is the `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800


[[runners]]
  name = "my-runner"
  url = "http://gitlab/"
  id = 3
  token = "glrt-rg-noV98QitS65raRQzk"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-12-05T10:33:20Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "alpine:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    network_mtu = 0
```

#### My understanding

The meaning of localhost inside the GitLab Runner container is different and it points to the container itself, not the host machine. So I tried to set the `extra_host` in different ways as follows:

- `extra_hosts = ["localhost:gitlab"]` : It reports error that the `gitlab` is not a valid url
- `extra_hosts = ["localhost:IP_ADDRESS_HOST_MACHINE"]`: didn't work
- `extra_hosts = ["localhost:IP_ADDRESS_GITLAB_CONTAINER"]`: didn't work

I also set `network_mode: "host"` in both services, but didn't work.

I have been grappling with this issue for about a week now, and I have tried various methods, but I haven't reached any conclusion.

Comment: Try setting the `clone_url` parameter in the `[[runners]]` section using the appropriate scheme host and port for the "inside" connection via the docker network. You shouldn't need extra hosts.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to reach gitlab through the docker network. Just set the [`clone_url` parameter](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section) accordingly.

```ini
[[ runners ]]
# ...
clone_url = "http://gitlab"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It reports error : `fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab/root/test.git/': Could not resolve host: gitlab`.

Comment: Finally, I used `clone_url = "http://172.17.0.1:1080` which is the IP address of the host and it worked. But it was surprising it didn't know the `gitlab`

Comment: The `gitlab` works for `url` config, but not `clone_url`